# Using Face API to augment identity services

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, face-api

My application is already based on Azure B2C, but I'd like to add face recognition as an additional, alternative sign in method (with pin, of course).  But this application would require onboarding users one at a time.

I've only done a quick perusal of the docs, but it looks like I have to add all my faces at once, instead of onboarding customers one at a time.  That won't work for me.

Do I understand this limitation correctly?
TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding/Deleting faces to different FaceLists or Persons in LargePersonGroup can be processed concurrently.

Same operations to one specific FaceList or Person in LargePersonGroup should be done sequentially.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I think I understand that you are saying that if I want to add a new person that I want to identify to a group of people, then I can do that during an onboarding process.  But if I want to add multiple images to a single individual, then I should do that in one operation instead of multiples.  Sounds a bit like a "person" is being locked during the update process, and that makes perfect sense.  I'll mark this as the answer, but let me know if I don't have it right?  Thanks!